# Data saved to text file is inconsistent

Tags: python, pyserial

My controller is receiving data from a radio module through a serial port, it's recording temperature and humidity to two decimal places every 1 second, using 'a' as a signal to time stamp it. For example:

```
a21.12 65.43
a21.13 65.40
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import serial
import datetime

connected = False

locations=['/dev/ttyUSB0','/dev/ttyUSB1','/dev/ttyUSB2','/dev/ttyUSB3']

for device in locations:
    try:
        print "Trying...",device
        ser = serial.Serial(device, 9600)
        break
    except:
        print "Failed to connect on",device

while not connected:
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True


with open('tempdata.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    while 1:
        if ser.read() is 'a':
            text_file.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
            text_file.write(" ")
        x = ser.read()
        text_file.write(x)
        text_file.flush()

ser.close()
```

When I check my text file afterwards the result seems to be different every time. If I let it run for just 2 or 3 seconds I sometimes get a correct result, sometimes I only get the humidity, sometimes I get the time stamp with a number that is half temperature, half humidity (like 2.16.3). If I let it run for more than a few seconds the file is just completely blank.

The basis for my code is from a question previously asked on here and it worked fine until I added the time stamp part. I tried changing the radio transfer rate from 9600 to 4800 but that just turned the numbers into garbage characters.

I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi 2 model B so I could be demanding too much from it in a short time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `read()` twice and writing only the output of the second call. I don't imagine that is your intent.

You can change this section:

```
with open('tempdata.txt', 'a') as text_file:
    while 1:
        content = ser.read()
        if content is 'a':
            text_file.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
            text_file.write(" ")
        text_file.write(content)
        text_file.flush()
```

Comment: That worked really well for fixing the output, thank you for that. I still get a completely blank text file if I let it run for more than 3 or 4 pulses.

Comment: You probably want to change the mode to append `'a'`